py ModuleNotFoundError with venv
I've got a venv set-up for Python. Once I active the venv, I can run scripts using python no problem.
But using the py launcher does not work.
py reports the correct location:
> py -0p
  *               C:\venv location\.venv\Scripts\python.exe
 -V:3.12          C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe
 -V:3.9           C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
 -V:3.7-32        C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe

Same results as python with venv active:
> Get-Command python

CommandType     Name           Version    Source
-----------     ----           -------    ------
Application     python.exe     3.12.21... C:\venv location\.venv\Scripts\python.exe

> python / py -c  "import sys; print(sys.path)"
Gives the same (correct) paths with both python and py, which include the correct .venv\Lib\site-packages
Scripts run fine with > python script.py
But > py script.py gives ModuleNotFoundError for all venv modules.
This is not a block: I can of course just keep using python instead of the py launcher. But it bugs me. I know I 'should' be using py, but I can't see why py isn't working?

I ran into this issue tonight myself, and I think I figured it out.
The script I was trying to run had the following shebang on the first line:
#! /usr/bin/env python3

The pylauncher utility uses the first line shebang to figure out which interpreter to use.  PEP 397
By specifying python3 in the shebang, pylauncher specifically looks for python3.exe instead of python.exe, and after failing to find python3.exe  in the virtual environment, it checks the system PATH, which on my system was a Python 3.9 installation in the msys64/mingw64 directory.
Changing the shebang to simply #! /usr/bin/env python allows pylauncher to find the active venv interpreter and run the script as expected.
Alternatively, you can completely remove the shebang, and pylauncher will find the venv interpreter.
Using #! /usr/bin/python did not work, as that instead launched the first version of Python found in PATH instead of the venv interpreter.
I haven't tested it yet, but according to the Python documentation for Using Python on Windows, this behavior is at least somewhat fixed in Python3.13

Changed in version 3.13: Virtual commands referencing python now prefer an active virtual environment rather than searching PATH. This handles cases where the shebang specifies /usr/bin/env python3 but python3.exe is not present in the active environment.

